# Oracle Update Left Join

Tags: oracle, join, update

I have this MYSQL code butt I am unsure how to convert it to oracle database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
UPDATE product p
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM order_detail
GROUP BY product_name
) AS d ON d.product_name = p.product_name
SET p.order_quantity = IFNULL(d.quantity, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar syntax in Oracle using an updatable view. This is where you write the query as a select statement and update. However, this requires a guarantee that the joins can't be one-to-many (this requirement is relaxed in the latest version but I wouldn't expect that to be relevant here).

Instead, you can just use a scalar subquery in a regular `update` statement.

```
UPDATE product p
SET    p.order_quantity = 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM   order_detail d
WHERE  d.product_name = p.product_name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can usee a view for that

see more [information](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/updates-based-on-queries) about that problem

> ```
> CREATE TABLE product (c1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1), order_quantity int ,product_name varchar(110))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO product (order_quantity,product_name) VALUES (10,'A');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO product (order_quantity,product_name)  VALUES (11,'B');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE order_detail (c1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),quantity int ,product_name varchar(110))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_detail (quantity,product_name) VALUES (5,'A')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_detail (quantity,product_name) VALUES (5,'A');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE (SELECT p.order_quantity,
>                 COALESCE(d.quantity,0) quantity
>         FROM   product p LEFT JOIN (
> SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS quantity
> FROM order_detail GROUP BY product_name) d ON d.product_name = p.product_name
>
>         ) ilv
> SET ilv.order_quantity = ilv.quantity;
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM product
> ```
>
> ```
> C1 | ORDER_QUANTITY | PRODUCT_NAME
> -: | -------------: | :-----------
>  1 |              2 | A           
>  2 |              0 | B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5bac171cbce3571a10198b6bb6bd9d0)*